# Nginx, .Htaccess and try_files

Tags: .htaccess, nginx

I need to convert this htaccess file into try_files for nginx but I cannot do it for the life of me. Can someone please help?

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^img-(.*)\.html img.php?id=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^slide-(.*)\.html slider.php?id=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^page-(.*)\.html page.php?name=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^contact\.html$ contact.php [QSA,L,NC]
```

Comment: What do you want to do with try_files? Here simple rewrites should work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need try_files here:

```
rewrite ^/img-(.*).html$ /img.php?id=$1 last;
rewrite ^/slide-(.*).html$ /slider.php?id=$1 last;
rewrite ^/page-(.*).html$ /page.php?name=$1 last;
rewrite ^/contact.html$ /contact.php last;
```